# redis blocking peek in ruby, in other words, block pop without removing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I use rpush and blpop all the time for message queue since both of them are very efficient blocking method. Is there any block peek method available in redis instead of pop?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such a method but if you have just one "peeking" process and no worries about scalability, perhaps something like [`BRPOPLPUSH peekqueue realqueue 0`](http://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush) would work for you.

Comment: BRPOPLPUSH peekqueue peekqueue 0; maybe just put back to the same queue again?

Comment: 'fraid not. Even with one peeker and one item in the queue, that would result in an infinite loop. With more than one item and attaching workers to the queue - the peeker will loose items between peeks.